# Runtime closes when I use DoCmd.OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime

I have a form with a button which opens a new form to add a new record to a table.

In Access on my PC (full version), everything works.

When I try to run it on a server with Access Runtime, I get an error saying something like:

> this application has stopped working due to a runtime-error. The
>   application will now be closed

(I have the Dutch version, so I hope this comes close to the English dialog box message).

I debugged the VBA, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

It has worked before:

```
Private Sub Knop62_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Machines Toevoegen", , , , acFormAdd, _
      acDialog, OpenArgs:=Me.Installaties_Id
End Sub
```

Comment: The form exists and is spelled exactly as ```Machines Toevoegen```, and ```me.Installaties_Id``` exists and is spelled properly?

Comment: `OpenArgs:=` is not necessary but shouldn't hurt. Don't see anything wrong with command.

Comment: I would guess: the form or its code uses something that is installed on your computer, but not on the server. The fact that the latter uses Access runtime may be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Well any un-handled error in the runtime will spit out the error message, and then as you experienced exit the application.

there are a good number of ways to approach this:
Improve error handling - make sure you don't encounter any un-handled error. I find this can be a LOT of work.

Another way? Compile your application down to a accDE. When you use a accDE, not only does the runtime ignore errors, not only does it NOT shut down?

It also means that all of your local and global variables are NEVER re-set. so global vars, and even global reocrdsets or anything else will retain their values, and do so even with errors. As a result:
Your application runs like a un-stoppable fright train.
Your local and even global variables retain their values. This allows use of application wide settings and variables that never re-set. And no re-sets ever occur even for un-handled errors. They remain intact for the given session (since the time the application was launched).

So, I would try running your application as a accDE on that server. It will not only become  vastly more reliable, but it will also not shutdown on un-expected errors and even better it will retain the value of variables even when having encountered errors.

So it looks like you have some un-handed error. You can go on a treasure hunt to find this error, or just try a accDE in the meantime, and perhaps in the new years you might eventually track down the error or issue. But until then, just compile your application as a accDE.

To compile:
First, from VBA editor (just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>). And from the menu bar choose debug->compile. You MUST ensure that no compile errors exist before the next step.

If above compiles, then from UI (main ribbon), go file->Save and publish

From that panel, choose Make ACCDE.

Access will compile your application into a "access executable". Now try running this application with a accDE file extension on the other computer.

Comment: Awesome, this might in fact help a lot. Only problem is: I made the DB in Access 2016, server runs 2010... So the ACCDE I make with 2016 doesn't run on 2010, any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: as a general rule, you ALWAYS want to develop with the lowest common version of Access you plan to deploy to. This advice actually applies to even when using  accDB. As new features are added then you can never be sure that you can go back in time. I can't take a new Word document and open it with say Word running on old windows 3.1. Compatibility in this industry is great moving forward in time, but attempting to run a newer version of software system X with a previous version is a VERY bad idea. You have to either adopt 2010 for your development, and then can deploy to 2013, 2016, 2019 etc.

Comment: So either you install 2016 run time on that server, or you adopt 2010 for your development cycle.  You as a general rule MUST develop with the lowest common version of Access you plan to deploy to. So if you use 2013, then your runtime will work with 2013, 2016 and 2019. You can no more run a new version of Word on a old DOS computer without a mouse then you can attempt to go backwards with Access in time. So, you have to install the newer version of the runtime, or you have to use 2010 for your development. So look at what versions of Access you will deploy to and use lowest common edition.